# Problems trying to deserialize string into a object

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, .net-1.1

today I have a simple json object like this:

```
[
    {
        "Code": "My Sample Code",
        "Description": "My Sample Description",
        "Permissions": [
            {
                "Id": 432,
                "Name": "FIRSTPERMISSION"
            },
            {
                "Id": 32,
                "Name": "SECONDPERMISSION"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And I`m trying to bind it to an object.
But the problem is: I'm on .Net Framework 1.1, which doesn't have the principal classes to do this work, like:

- None of the Newtonsoft.Json (Json.Net) classes
- System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer
- System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
- System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer

And I tried to add Newtonsoft.Json reference from .net framework 2.0 to my app, without success.

How can I put the json string values into a object, to work with this?

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: [JSON Object Serializer .Net 1.1](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=jsonserializer). Never tested.

Comment: Hello Jimi, I tried, but Json Object Serializer, is only for Serialize an Object to a Json String, also I have opened the source code to check if I'm wrong. But not :/
Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: upgrade to a newer framework ;)

Comment: I'd agree on the upgrade.  Why fight this in an ancient framework when the tools are easily available in supported frameworks m

Comment: This other: [JSON.NET Framework for .NET 1.1](http://www.chiefmillso.com/blog/index.php?itemid=11)

Comment: Thanks again Jimi !! But the guy never published the framework in codeplex, and also not posted a link to download the dll. :-|

Comment: Darkonekt and Brian White, I'd agree with you, but that decision cannot be mine. I've alerted our strategic manager.

Comment: It's not a `.dll`, it's a zipped file with the full project inside. You can build a library yourself. Or move on :)

Comment: Could you switch to XML?   I recall there was a working XML serializer in .Net 1.1.

Comment: Most serialisation code relies on generics for even the simplest types of collections. You can probably rework some JSON serialisation code like [the one in Unit](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/5576685231e21b37341be7fa7197cde88ed7ada5/src/common/Json.cs) to not use generics but you will have a hard time.

Comment: Out of context: Why does the project require 1.1? Is there a reason not to upgrade The only platform that 1.1 supports which 2.0+ don't is Windows NT 4.0.. And 2.0+ even have a lot of compatibility options (e.g. you can still get the "wrong" unicode modifier order from 1.0 in WinForms today if you really need)